# When do we use self. or [self ] in stringWithFormat?

Tags: objective-c

When using stringWithFormat for an NSString in a return statement when do we use self. ; [self ] or just the instance?

For example, we have return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@" , self.someinstance or [self someinstance] or someinstance].

Comment: Are you asking what the differences between using `self.propertyName`, `[self propertyName]`, and `_propertyName` are? If so, then `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: When used with a return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.someinstance` is equivalent to `[self someinstance]`. The former is just using dot-syntax that became available in Objective-C 2.0.

It's mostly a personal preference as to which option you use. I would suggest being consistent throughout your app and always use one format.

Using `someinstance` on its own, without `self.` or `[self ]`, is different and accesses the instance variable directly. This should be avoided outside of your `init` methods.

Comment: Why should I access instance variables within an init method?

Comment: If you use self.someinstance in the `init` method, it will call the getter/setter method on the instance, but the instance may not yet be fully initialized. This can cause weird, hard to track down bugs. General rule of thumb is to initialize the instance variable directly in the init method, and once everything has been initialized, it'll then be safe to use the getter/setter methods. Interestingly, this is enforced in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a convention thing, technically

```
 self.myProperty;
```

and

```
[self myProperty];
```

do exactly the same thing (access a property through the getter method)
Personally I always use dot-syntax for properties and [] for methods. I think I read somewhere ages ago this was the accepted convention, but I can't remember where.

```
_myProperty ;
```

will access the property directly, bypassing the getter/setters. I would advise against using this except for constructors and getter/setters though as KVO will not work if you do this. Also custom getter/setters will be pointless if you use this.